# python dictonary to callable

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have this class enum in my code.

```
class TimeDurationTypeَ(Enum, metaclass=ChoiceEnumMeta):
    d30 = "30d"
    d14 = "14d"
    d7 = "7d"
    d1 = "1d"
    hr12 = "12hr"
    hr6 = "6hr"
    hr1 = "1hr"
```

I want to be able to filter results (query) based on this time durations. I want to have a dictionary from these enum vals to callabe something like this:

```
TimeDuration2datetimeField = {
    TimeDurationTypeَ.d30: datetime.timedelta(days=-30),
}
```

so I can get this values in the filtering process. How to have such a dictionary? Or is there a better way for this situation?

Comment: Instead doing this, you can use static dict variables inside the same ORM class, where each of key `d30` will be assigned by another dict with values `{"days": -30}`. Then pass the value to filter using double star **